# Webdriver: Locate typefield via placeholder text then text via sendkey("test text") into the typefield

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been trying to send a text to a text field that has the changing element `id=PolarisTextField83` each time a log into a page (PolarisTextField## keeps changing its value like `id=PolarisTextField45`) as I have found that the id element is dynamic and the only static and unique part of the HTML is the placeholder example text which is `placeholder="e.g. Shirts"`.

Therefore, I wonder if there is a way of locating `placeholder="e.g. Shirts"` then sending text to its respective type field (PolarisTextField##)?

I have tried to use

```
driver.findElementsByTagName("e.g. Shirts").sendKeys("test text");
```

but came to the understanding that I cannot follow `.sendKeys()` after `findElementsByTagName`.

I am new to both java and selenium and would appreciate any help and/or guidance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the element by placeholder value using XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='e.g. Shirts']")).sendKeys("test text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath to deal with dynamic web element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'PolarisTextField')]")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`, *id* and *placeholder* attributes:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='PolarisTextField'][placeholder$='Shirts']")).sendKeys("test text");
  ```
- Using `xpath`, *id* and *placeholder* attributes:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'Shirts') and contains(@placeholder, 'Shirts')]")).sendKeys("test text");
  ```

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* within the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[id^='PolarisTextField'][placeholder$='Shirts']"))).sendKeys("test text");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'Shirts') and contains(@placeholder, 'Shirts')]"))).sendKeys("test text");
  ```